# Why does google map appear grey and not initialize zoom & center when using buttons with jQuery to change zoom and center on the map works perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google map api to make a map with custom markers and button that change the center and zoom of the map. I have a global variable for the map and infoWindow. My map appears grey without zoom controls when it's initialized.
I do not have any error messages showing in the console. 
I have five buttons called : Asia , NorthAmerica, middleEast, newYork, newEngland. The buttons work to change the center and the zoom of the map.
But I want the map to start at the initial position in the

```
var mapOptions= {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.423734,27.142826), 
    zoom: map.setZoom(4)
  };
```

I use a foreach loop through an object of locations to customize the markers and infoWindows on the map. I also have a function to set the type of makers. That works great.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var map, infoWindow;
```

---

### function for type of custom marker

```
function initMap() {

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.423734,27.142826), 
    zoom: map.setZoom(4)
  };

$("#asia").on('click', function () {
newLocation(37.566535,126.977969,5);
});
$("#northAmerica").on('click', function () {
newLocation(30.902225,-90.659180,4);
});
$("#middleEast").on('click', function () {
newLocation(38.423734,27.142826,4);
});
$("#newYork").on('click', function () {
newLocation(40.753159,-73.98936,12);
});
$("#newEngland").on('click', function () {
newLocation(42.292783,-71.304496,7);
});
```

**'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);'**  is part of my initMap function after the for loops add the custom markers.

After I close the initMap function but still in the $(document).ready(function(){ initMap is called and function newLocation is defined 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

---

for each loop for custom markers

### object of custom markers locations and infoWindow content

```
function newLocation(newLat,newLng,newZoom) {
map.setCenter({
    lat : newLat,
    lng : newLng,
  }); 
map.setZoom(newZoom)
};

initMap();

});
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I get a javasscript error with your posted `initMap` function: `Uncaught TypeError: map.setZoom is not a function` on this line: `zoom: map.setZoom(4)` (which should be: `zoom: 4`)

Answer (score 0):

I get a javasscript error with your posted `initMap` function: `Uncaught TypeError: map.setZoom is not a function` on this line: `zoom: map.setZoom(4)`

that should be: `zoom: 4`

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.423734, 27.142826),
    zoom: 4
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)

  $("#asia").on('click', function() {
    newLocation(37.566535, 126.977969, 5);
  });
  $("#northAmerica").on('click', function() {
    newLocation(30.902225, -90.659180, 4);
  });
  $("#middleEast").on('click', function() {
    newLocation(38.423734, 27.142826, 4);
  });
  $("#newYork").on('click', function() {
    newLocation(40.753159, -73.98936, 12);
  });
  $("#newEngland").on('click', function() {
    newLocation(42.292783, -71.304496, 7);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function newLocation(newLat, newLng, newZoom) {
  map.setCenter({
    lat: newLat,
    lng: newLng,
  });
  map.setZoom(newZoom)
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="asia" value="asia" type="button" />
<input id="northAmerica" value="northAmerica" type="button" />
<input id="middleEast" value="middleEast" type="button" />
<input id="newYork" value="newYork" type="button" />
<input id="newEngland" value="newEngland" type="button" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip When I changed the zoom to zoom:4  my map was still grey.   **bold  ' google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);'  bold**  is part of my initMap function after the for loops add the custom markers.  After I close the initMap function but still in the $(document).ready(function(){  initMap is called and function newLocation is defined

Comment: Yes, the code snippet works for me I figured out my problem now mine works too. I had to change  **bold 'map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)' bold**  to after the var mapOptions like your code snippet now it works  Thank you again @geocodezip

Comment: if this solved your problem/answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)